# Return an object when overriding a virtual void method? C++

Tags: c++, return, overriding, virtual

So I am using a generic abstract class called Object, and the virtual update method for that class is of return type void.

```
virtual void update(std::string, int, std::vector<Object*>) = 0;
```

However I need to return an object from a Player class that I extend from the Object class.

```
Object update(std::string , int , std::vector<Object*>);
```

But when I try to override the function's return type I get the following error:

```
error C2555: 'Player::update': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'Object::update'
```

From what I've been able to find do this is bad form for some reason. I didn't really understand why though. I need to create new objects within the player class and return them to the engine to be used in the vector of objects that will be updated within the engine. Why would this be bad practice, and how can I accomplish the same goal via another method?

So I altered the program along George Kourtis's answer, but now I ran into another set of issues. I need to loop through a vector of Object pointers (everything in the game extends from the abstract Object class for this reason) and update each object. If I overload the player update method to include a object pointer as both the return type and an argument, then how can I update the player from the vector loop? I need to specify that this particular Object* from the vector of type Object* is a Player object so that it will then accept the overloaded update function.

```
void Engine::objectUpdate(string command){

    if((*currentObject)->getType() == PLAYER){
        Bullet* tempBullet = new Bullet();
        tempBullet = (*currentObject)->update(command,getNumObjects(),subVector,tempBullet);
        subVector.push_back(tempBullet);
    }
    else{
        (*currentObject)->update(command,getNumObjects(),getObjects());
    }

    if(((*currentObject)->getType() == PLAYER)&&((*currentObject)->getPosX()>=getFinishLine())){
        setGameOver(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice because of the reasons reported by the error. You're cannot overload member functions that way since the return type is not considered during overload and override resolution. if you need to return an object you'll need to revisit your design and make changes to the base class as necessary. Also returning by copy is probably wrong here.

Comment: You cannot! Do you have the ability to change the pure virtual method in the base class?

Comment: If `Object` is indeed abstract, that return value is already invalid, as instantiating a *real* abstract base (pure virtuals and all) isn't allowed. I sense a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use overloading, the compiler knows which function to call by examining the type of the parameters passed. So if the parameters are the same, then the possible choice should be only one. In your case, there are two possible candidates differing only in the result. In case you need an alternative route, create your alternative function by passing as last parameter the "result" object as an argument passed by reference. –

instead of

```
Object update(std::string , int , std::vector<Object*>);

void update(std::string , int , std::vector<Object*>, Object& o);
```

Instead of writing:

```
Object a=update(s,i,v);
```

you will write:

```
Object a;update(s,i,v,a);
```

Comment: I implemented an overload function, but how would I use the overload function from a vector of Object* ? It does not recognize the overloaded  player function because it only approaches the object pointers from the base class.

Comment: @George Give them an appropriate sample, how to do that right please.

Comment: I need to specify to the compiler that the current Object* that is held by the iterator is a Player Object so that I can use the overloaded update method. I updated the original question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade the type of pointer to the required type ( player ). There are a lot of questions and answers about downgrading, so you could look at them. Any way the change of pointer may be done as usually as (Player*) ObjectpPtr , but that may be problematic if you aren't sure the Object is really of Player type, instead you could overload the function as a virtual inside Object and implement it only in Player, and in that case it shouldn't be necessary to do that type casting.